# Trying o install 2 apps together in the same device whith android 5 error -505

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Hi I have a big problem with android 5.

I developed 2 apps that was signed with different keys (and with different package name) but when I try to install those signed apps together doesn't work. I only can install one at each time. This problem only happen with android 5.

Comment: Can you please explain on what happens? Does the new one uninstall the old one, do you get a wraning that an app with the same package is installed?

Comment: Its too rare what it happens. the two apps are in the playstore (this certify that are signed with different package name and different keystore). But when i try install the first one (doesn't matter the order) works perfect but when try install the second one show an **error -505**

Comment: duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/how-do-i-deal-with-unknown-installation-error-code-505

Comment: As I can see there is not solution yet because solution involves that the user manipulate its device. I would like as developer do something to solve this issue transparently to user